# Using pdb inside a Robot Framework file

Tags: python, robotframework, pdb

I need to set debugger from a robot file to debug and I followed the instruction on the documentation [here](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#using-the-python-debugger-pdb:%7E:text=Evaluate%20%20%20%20pdb.Pdb(stdout%3Dsys.__stdout__).set_trace()%20%20%20%20modules%3Dsys%2C%20pdb)

```
Evaluate    pdb.Pdb(stdout=sys.__stdout__).set_trace()    modules=sys, pdb
```

But when I run that robot file, I have this error:

```
Evaluating expression 'pdb.Pdb(stdout=sys.__stdout__).set_trace()' failed: NameError: name '__args__' is not defined nor importable as module
```

I am not sure what is holding this. Did anyone have this issue or any solution? Thanks so much

Comment: I copypasted your command and could not reproduce this. What version are you using? I have `Robot Framework 6.0.2 (Python 3.11.1 on win32)`